# How to separate a string with the key/value pairs for different configurations?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

The output below is what I get when I run `alias impala` (except that it is on one line without the backslashes).  However, I would like to extract the bold information and assign it to variables dynamically while reading this information from a text file.  I need help or a pattern command to extract the information and assign it to variables which will also be used for other purposes.

```sh
alias impala = 'impala-shell -i **<serverinfowith.net.net>** --database=**abcd** \
--kerberos --kerberos_service_name=**xyzq** --ssl \
--ca_cert=**/ab/cd/ef/gh/abc.pem** --query_option=ABC_SYNC=1'
```

Comment: The short answer is "do not use an alias — use a function or a script".  Personally, I'd use a script rather than a function.  In the script (or function), you can do whatever analysis you need to pull values from a text file and substitute those into the command.

Comment: Hi Jonathan its not alias I am using , its a environment variable set on the server level, I can use this to extract the needed information dynamically, and then create variables - this way when I run this across different environment I get different host /db and other information which will be used for different property file creation.

Comment: Sorry you can ignore the alias - Treat the information provided is in the text file, how through unix commands or awk I can extract the bolded information and assign to variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
set -- $(sed 's/.*-i \([^[:space:]]*\) --database=\([^[:space:]]*\) .*_name=\([^[:space:]]*\) --ssl --ca_cert=\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1 \2 \3 \4/' filename)
server="$1"
dbase="$2"
service="$3"
cert="$4"
```

The regex is gruesome but captures the four strings you're interested in between `\(` and `\)` each time.  You can reduce the context if you prefer.  You could write `[^ ]` instead of `[^[:space:]]` each time, as long as you're confident no-one will use any tabs in the file.  The `filename` is the file containing the string (`alias` command) shown in the question.  The `set --` sets the positional arguments (`$1`..`$4`) from the output from the `sed` command.  The assignments give names to the values in the positional arguments.